# MongoDB reference vs nested

Tags: python, performance, database-design, mongodb, schema

I want to store 'status updates' in mongodb. Therefore this collection/array can get very big.
I think one option would be to save the documents in an array nested in the user/group/... document.(Different collections need their own 'status updates')
The other way would be to create another collection save the messages their and relate the user/group/... to the status updates via another objectId 
I want to know

- what is faster
- what is easier to administrate and query

I think I'm not going to use an orm/drm just "plain" pymongo.
 
I haven't found any clear answer in the docs, maybe someone already tested this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an older presentation, but still relevant for these kinds of questions, and discusses some of the tradeoffs.

http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosf2011/schemascale

TLDR(W) - it depends how many updates is "very big", and how you're accessing them.  If you always need to access the full set at once and they're < 16MB, you can embed, if you generally need only a few at a time you can link.  There's also a hybrid approach which is to embed recent and link the rest.